Mobile broadband disabled after losing signal
I have a GETAC F1100 tablet with a cellular modem running linux. If I run to the basement and connection is lost, the mobile broadband is disabled and does not connect automatically if I get connection again.
I set all the reconnect options in configuration file of my custom profile.
The problem is fixed if I restart the Network Manager with sudo systemctl restart NetworkManager.
I set up the custom profile with
sudo nmcli connection add type gsm ifname '*' con-name my-conn apn my-apn

connection profile in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/my-conn.nmconnection
[connection]
id=my-conn
uuid=<unique for each device>
type=gsm
autoconnect=true
autoconnect-retries=0

[gsm]
apn=my-apn

[ipv4]
dns-priority=120
method=auto
route-metric=1050

[ipv6]
addr-gen-mode=stable-privacy
method=auto

[proxy]

system info
linux 21.04

Not a current version of Ubuntu, the only OS supported on this site. Sorry.

Ubuntu 21.04 (along with all flavors) is End-of-Life and thus unsupported on this site (https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic), and many other Ubuntu sites, unless your question is specific to moving to a supported release of Ubuntu. https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2022/01/21/ubuntu-21-04-hirsute-hippo-end-of-life-reached-on-january-20-2022/  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/EOLUpgrades
